# MySQL and word boundary in regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

How can I use regex word boundary in a MySQL query?

For instance, I want to match either 'product' or 'newsletter',

It works fine with `OR`,

```
IF(? = 'product' OR ? = 'newsletter', ... , ...)
```

But how about a regex? I assume it would be something like this below?

```
IF(? REGEXP '^('product'||'newsletter')+$', ..., ... )
```

Comment: What about `... IN ('product', 'newsletter')`?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE description REGEXP '[[:<:]]red[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]blue[[:>:]]'
```

or, as a select expression:

```
SELECT IF(description REGEXP '[[:<:]]red[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]blue[[:>:]]', 1, 0) AS is_matched, tbl.*
FROM description
```

You can use `RLIKE` as a synonym but `REGEXP` seems to be more popular <sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

### Case Sensitivity

From the [MySQL manual for REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' REGEXP 'A', 'a' REGEXP BINARY 'A';
        -> 1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP` or `RLIKE`.

[`Regular expressions in MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

In your case, you could use [`MATCH() ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) fulltext search with MyISAM storage engine.

Or you could use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) as @Wiseguy mentioned